# Adding GPS support to a Wi-Fi only iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, gps

I have been reading on this, and so far the option I found is:

- Garmin/XGPS external Bluetooth GPS receiver

And that is it. Are there any other alternatives?

I’m curious if an Android or iPhone could be used to share its GPS. I should have gotten a Wi-Fi + cellular iPad, but thats a different story.

Answer (score 2):

## Using External GPS / GNSS With iOS

This requires :

1. The external GPS must be a Made for iPod (MFI) certified External Accessory (EA) that support iOS (has the Apple authentication chip) via a Bluetooth connection to the GPS
2. Requires that iOS Core Location Services be overridden by one of two methods so that all apps on the iPhone/iPad will use the external GPS.

   - 1) Use of an app such as [EOS Tools Pro](https://eos-gnss.com/product/tools-apps/eos-tools-pro/) that receives location information and overrides iOS Core Location Services.
   - 2) The External Accessory (EA) itself somehow overrides iOS Core Location Services.
     I do not understand how this is done.
     Only devices made by SXblue https://sxbluegps.com/products/gps-gnss-receivers/ can do this MFI magic AFAIK.

I have found only a few GPS manufactures that support iOS:

- [BadElf](https://bad-elf.com/) (lower accuracy but lower cost)
- EOS https://eos-gnss.com/product/arrow-series/arrow-gold/
- BlueStar (rebranded EOS devices) http://bluestargps.com/index.html
- SXblue https://sxbluegps.com/
- EOS (BluStar is EOS Arrow 200 I *think*). All these EOS devices support iOS:
- https://eos-gnss.com/comparison-chart

## Sharing Android GPS with an IOS Device

I have no idea if this works.

[How To Share GPS From An Android Phone To An iPad [Guide]](https://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-share-gps-from-an-android-phone-to-an-ipad-guide/)

Comment: Reading on BlueStar's page, it seems their products are for Android devices, and not iOS.

Comment: @Andreas The BlueStar works well on iOS using the free 3rd party EOS Tools Pro (available on both Android and IOS).   EOS Tools Pro communicates with the BlueStar and replaces the iOS device core location services with the highly accurate location info coming from the BlueStar GNSS   https://apps.apple.com/us/app/eos-tools-pro/id961459993

Comment: I *think* the BluStar is a re-labeled EOS Arrow 200.  All of these support iOS. https://eos-gnss.com/comparison-chart

Comment: You are right that I can find NO mention of iOS on the http://bluestargps.com/ website.

Answer (score 1):

Wi-Fi only iPad doesn't come with built in GPS and other positioning hardware (GLONASS, Galileo, and QZSS) which are available in current models of iPhone and Wi-Fi + Cellular models of iPad.

You can search the Web and find various wired/wireless (Bluetooth) accessories for your iPad that provide positioning functionality using GPS and a companion app.

> I’m curious if an Android or iPhone could be used to share its GPS.

Generally speaking, an Android or iPhone can't be used out of the box as a GPS (positioning) accessory for your Wi-Fi only iPad. It is technically possible to create an app which will let you pair your iPad with a mobile device and view the positioning data, but the same can be done on the mobile device itself.

Comment: A friend bought an iPad in dec 2019. The sales person told him there are no longer any iPads that don't have the GPS feature for positioning. But as far as I know he still has not been able to get it to show his position on the map. On your answer it seems the sales person was wrong, if you know this to be a fact in late 2019.

Comment: @AndreasJansson If you take a look at this page: https://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/ and scroll down to "Cellular + Wireless" section, you'd see that GPS hardware is still exclusive to Cellular models (in 2020). That's true for all the iPad ever manufactured till date.